# What python module can I use to manipulate onscreen graphics?

Tags: python, module

This is a bit hard to explain, but I'm looking for a python module I can install that would allow me to manipulate what I'm presently viewing on-screen (specifically, changing the colour hue of the visuals).

For example, changing it so that what I'm seeing is presented in black and white, or altering it so it's primarily red hued or blue hued etc.

Is there any module that can do this?

Comment: Do you mean alter an image that is displayed in the python program or change the monitor settings / colour profile of computer?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I apologise as I wasn't clear. Not an image displayed in the python program, but, it's hard to explain. Basically like it intercepts what the graphics card produces on-screen, but applies a colour filter to it.